# matplotlib azimuth vs elevation - discontinuity at origin

Tags: matplotlib, plot, elevation, azimuth

A conventional way to plot the sun position is to plot the hourly azimuth (roughly the position of the sun away from North) against the elevation (height above horizon). In the southern hemisphere, this means the azimuth ranges from 180 degrees (say midnight am) through to 0 degrees at solar noon. But the convention then requires the afternoon azimuth to start at 360 degrees and decrease to 180 degrees towards midnight. So there is an abrupt change at noon, where the azimuth goes from 0 to 360 degrees as shown in the image below:

[image: example figure]

I can't find a way to change the x-axis in matplotlib (pyplot) so that it has such a discontinuity at the origin. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could plot your data in two parts (morning and afternoon separately) into the correct areas of your `Axis` and then achieve the flip by setting your `xtick_labels` 'by hand'.

Comment: That seems to work, but as you say, the data doesn't look right. The chart looks like a plot of elevation versus hour of the day, so I think your azimuth calculation is wrong. The more accurate angle requires calculation of hour angle and declination as well as latitude. I'll see if I can use my data with your plot code.

Answer (score 0):

You could plot your data in two parts (morning and afternoon separately) into the correct areas of your `Axis` and then achieve the flip by setting your `xtick_labels` 'by hand'. Below an example how to do it in principle (the data doesn't look very much like the data in your original plot, though):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#latitude:
lat = -36.55

#declination:
def delta(N):
    return -23.44*np.cos(360/365*(N+10))

azimuth_morning = np.linspace(180,0,50)
azimuth_afternoon = np.linspace(360,180,50)

def zenith(azimuth, lat, N):
    return np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(
        np.sin(np.deg2rad(lat))*np.sin(np.deg2rad(delta(N)))+
        np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat))*np.cos(np.deg2rad(delta(N)))*
        np.cos(np.deg2rad(azimuth))
    ))


def plot_sun_arc(ax, N):
    ax.plot(180+azimuth_morning,zenith(azimuth_morning,lat,N),'k')
    ax.plot(azimuth_afternoon-180,zenith(azimuth_afternoon,lat,N),'k')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

for N in range(0,366,60):
    plot_sun_arc(ax,N)

xticks = [i for i in range(0,361, 20)]
xtick_labels = ['{}'.format(t+180) if t < 180 else '{}'.format(t-180) for t in xticks]

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xtick_labels)

ax.set_xlim([0,360])
ax.set_ylim([0,90])

plt.show()
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image: figure that results from the posted code]